# Change info on sidebar according with marker clicked using Leaflet

Tags: javascript, json, onclick, leaflet, geojson

I'm having a hard time finalizing a project because of not being able to change the information in my sidebar according to the data obtained through a json according to the clicked marker. Is my code:

basic json:

```
paradas = {
    "type" : "FeatureCollection",
    "name" : "paradas",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
          "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "features" : [
        { 
            "type" : "Feature", 
            "properties" : {  
                "nome" : "Parada 1", 
                "imagem" : "<img src='1.jpg' alt='maptime logo gif' width='350px'/>",
                "descricao" : "Test."
            }, 
            "geometry" : { 
                "type" : "Point", 
                "coordinates" : [
                    -38.55222702026367,
                    -3.7864725817550275
                ] 
            }
        },
       (... repeat json)
```

My html of the sidebar:

```
<div class="sidebar">
            <div class="nome"></div>
            <div class="imagem"></div>
            <div class="descricao"></div>
    </div>
```

My JS:

```
var rotas = L.geoJSON(paradas, {

}).addTo(map);
```

With just it, I can show the marker, but I can not continue, when I click on any and change the information of the sidebar. The logic I know, but I can not implement for lack of knowledge :(
I'm sorry for the basic doubt, but Can you help me just this time? Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should **add function that handles onEachFeature click**. Assuming you are using jquery (simplest solution):

```
var rotas = L.geoJSON(paradas, {
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  layer.on('click', function(e) {
    $(".nome").html(feature.properties.nome);
    $(".imagem").html(feature.properties.imagem);
    $(".descricao").html(feature.properties.descricao);
  });
}
```

**Working example** on codepen: [**https://codepen.io/dagmara223/pen/BVBGKG**](https://codepen.io/dagmara223/pen/BVBGKG)

Comment: BTW you can also "delegate" the event listener on the `rotas` layer group.